# PHP - PHPDoc typehint when trying to iterate over integer

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have this code

```php
/** @var array{total: integer, records: array} $response */
$response = $this->getResponse();

foreach($response['total'] as $value) {
    $this->saveRecord($value);
}
```

Shouldn't PhpStorm give me a warning using PHPDoc static analysis that I'm trying to iterate over `$response['total']`, which is an integer ?

Comment: I added the PHPStorm tag to your question because this is a question about that IDE.

Comment: FWIW, https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types#array-shapes agrees with you.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, we add the `mixed` type to all array shapes, that is why the inspection isn't triggered.

You can check what type any symbol holds by selecting it and clicking *View | Type Info*.

[image]
Please vote for [WI-61678](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-61678/Dont-add-mixed-for-array-access-with-defined-via-the-array-shape-key).

Comment: Not sure on this (why `array<int>`?)... unless I've got the initial example completely wrong...

Comment: I totally missed what the question was about. It's about the fact that the OP can iterate over an integer, and not about `$value` holding the wrong type (even though the root cause is the same). Thank you, I've corrected the answer